# Decoding XML in Base64 ActionScript 3.0

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash, base64, decode

I'm trying to import an XML file that has been Base64 encoded in Flash. The import is fairly simple:

```
var myXML:XML;
var myLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
myLoader.load(new URLRequest("encoded.xml"));
myLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, processXML);

function processXML(e:Event):void
{
    myXML = new XML(e.target.data);
    trace(myXML);
}
```

Now I am wondering how I decode it. I found a class that I think will work but I am unsure how to apply it to the XML once it is imported. My question is how would I use the class below to decode the XML or is there another way I should go about it?

```
package com.base64 { 
    /**
    * Encodes and decodes a base64 string.
    * @authors Sven Dens - http://www.svendens.be
    * @version 0.1
    *
    * Original Javascript implementation:
    * Aardwulf Systems, www.aardwulf.com
    * See: http://www.aardwulf.com/tutor/base64/base64.html
    */
    import flash.system.System;

    public class Base64 {
        /**
        * Variables
        * @exclude
        */
        protected static var base64chars:String = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=";

        /**
        * Encodes a base64 string.
        */
        public static function encode(src:String):String {
            var i:Number = 0;
            var output:String = new String("");
            var chr1:Number, chr2:Number, chr3:Number;
            var enc1:Number, enc2:Number, enc3:Number, enc4:Number;
            while (i < src.length) {
                chr1 = src.charCodeAt(i++);
                chr2 = src.charCodeAt(i++);
                chr3 = src.charCodeAt(i++);
                enc1 = chr1 >> 2;
                enc2 = ((chr1 & 3) << 4) | (chr2 >> 4);
                enc3 = ((chr2 & 15) << 2) | (chr3 >> 6);
                enc4 = chr3 & 63;
                if(isNaN(chr2)) enc3 = enc4 = 64;
                else if(isNaN(chr3)) enc4 = 64;
                output += base64chars.charAt(enc1)+base64chars.charAt(enc2);
                output += base64chars.charAt(enc3)+base64chars.charAt(enc4)
            }
            return output;
        }

        /**
        * Decodes a base64 string.
        */
        public static function decode(src:String):String {
            var i:Number = 0;
            var output:String = new String("");
            var chr1:Number, chr2:Number, chr3:Number;
            var enc1:Number, enc2:Number, enc3:Number, enc4:Number;
            while (i < src.length) {
                enc1 = base64chars.indexOf(src.charAt(i++));
                enc2 = base64chars.indexOf(src.charAt(i++));
                enc3 = base64chars.indexOf(src.charAt(i++));
                enc4 = base64chars.indexOf(src.charAt(i++));
                chr1 = (enc1 << 2) | (enc2 >> 4);
                chr2 = ((enc2 & 15) << 4) | (enc3 >> 2);
                chr3 = ((enc3 & 3) << 6) | enc4;
                output += String.fromCharCode(chr1);
                if (enc3 != 64) output = output+String.fromCharCode(chr2);
                if (enc4 != 64) output = output+String.fromCharCode(chr3);
            }
            return output;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, using your class, it should be as simple as

```
myXML = XML(Base64.decode(e.target.data));
```

If it doesn't work, check the returned value of the decoder :

```
trace(Base64.decode(e.target.data));
```